# laragon project: DNS address could not be found

Tags: laravel, dns, laragon

I just installed `laragon`, on port 8080, because my port 80 is already used, and I can't access my project in "learnlaravel.test" but I can open my localhost `localhost:8080`.

**Error**:

> This site can’t be reached. learnlaravel.test’s DNS address could not
> be found. Diagnosing the problem

[laragon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pjg0.png)

[learnlaravel.test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehYSb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go in your project Directory via CMD
then Run command

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: I can access my laravel via http://127.0.0.1:8000 but can't through firstproject.test

Thank u before

Answer (score 0):

1. **Menu -> Apache -> sites-enabled -> delete all (auto)**
2. **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** right click -> properties on **hosts** file and uncheck the **"Read-only"**.
3. make sure **auto virtual host** is checked on laragon
4. restart laragon and try **your project folder name inside in www with .test** (or as specified in laragon setting) in the browser